# How to perform faster updation of data in my image using matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I'm coding an algorithm for lane detection,

This is the skeleton code I've used,

```
while ~isDone(video)
   currentFrame = getFrame(video);
   .
   . % Do segmentation and lane detection
   .
   figure(1),imshow(currentFrame),hold on
   figure(1),plot( theLinesThatWereDetected );
   pause(.0001); % without pause the plot command wouldn't work like a streamer.
end
```

This is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K881hFCyiQ8 of the simulation, 
Problem : The output video gets slower and slower after displaying each frame, but as soon as I close the figure window it automatically restarts(as the code's running) and it gets faster(check video). Why is this happening, is there some memory build up that is happening to slow down the plotting? What can I do to fast things up other than manually closing figure window?

I know there is a video.ShapeInserter object available which is faster than the plotting method I've used . The reason I didn't use it is because the changing the thickness of lines in thee video.ShapeInserter object came only in the 2014 release and I'm using 2013 version. I wanted very distinct thick lines for my lane detection.

Kindly give me suggestions.

**Edit:** This is the video after applying the edits suggested by Shai. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJ_may0hkaE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: instead of issuing a new call to 'plot' in the loop could you try to update de XData and YData properties of the line instead? That should be faster

Comment: Additionally, instead of pause use 'drawnow'

Comment: If you ever get a more recent version of matlab, I would recommend using `insertShape` function to draw the lines into the image, and `vision.VideoPlayer` to display it. `insertShape` now has an option to set line thickness.

Comment: @Dima Unfortunately, I'm using the 2013 version.

Comment: If you have a closed polygon, then you can use `vision.ShapeInserter` to draw a filled polygon, and make it semi-transparent.  That will make your lines visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem:

Basically, all frames are added to your figure one on top of the other due to the `hold on` state your axes handle is in. This causes memory buildup and slows you down.

#### Solution:

You should turn off `hold` after drawing the lines, so the `imshow` of the next frame will discard the previous frame.

```
imshow(currentFrame);
hold on;
plot( theLinesThatWereDetected  );
hold off; %// super critical!
drawnow; %// instead of pause
```

#### Comments:

1. As pointed by [Ander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588301/how-to-perform-faster-updation-of-data-in-my-image-using-matlab/26589312#comment41793125_26588301) it is better practice to use [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) instead of `pause(0.001)`.
2. Just changing `XData` and `YData` of your plot (as suggested by [Benoit_11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588301/how-to-perform-faster-updation-of-data-in-my-image-using-matlab/26589312#comment41792916_26588301)) will not be enough, it does not solve the memory waste caused by "holding" all the frames in the figure.

Comment: @Benoit_11 you are welcome, sorry for the typo in your user name.

Comment: @Benoit_11 in general, I believe updating `XData` and `YData` of a plot should be preferable to `hold on`/`hold off` switching. However, in this case you would need to do so to the `CData` of the frame, and that makes switching `hold` to be a slightly more attractive solution.

Comment: Brilliant! worked like a charm. Thank you, Ander, Benoit, shai.

Comment: h = imshow(currentFrame);
set(h,'XData',x,'YData',y);  Is this what @Benoit_11 had suggested?

Comment: @user10678 you need to have two handles: one for the image and one for the plot: `ih = imshow(currFrame); ph=plot(currentLane);` for the first time. Then, for all other frames `set(ih,'CData',currFrame);` and `set(ph, 'XData', laneX, 'YData', laneY);`. Though, since you plot two lanes, you might have more than a single `ph` handle. You will need to check this out yourself.